# Laravel save model, table doesn't exist

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, model

Hi I use `save` method in Model to create record.
But I get error that table `c` doesn't exist.
Even the generated query seems good.

TransactionController:

```
public function store(Request $request){
    return Transaction::create([]);
}
```

Transaction Model:

```
class Transaction extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'transactions';
}
```

Error:

```
{
    "message": "SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'shekel.c' doesn't exist (SQL: insert into `transactions` (`date_and_time`, `date`) values (2020-01-13 10:29:22, 2020-01-13 10:29:22))",
    "exception": "Illuminate\\Database\\QueryException",
    "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
    "line": 669,
    "trace": [
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 629,
            "function": "runQueryCallback",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 464,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Connection.php",
            "line": 416,
            "function": "statement",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Processors/Processor.php",
            "line": 32,
            "function": "insert",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Connection",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php",
            "line": 2670,
            "function": "processInsertGetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Processors\\Processor",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 1350,
            "function": "insertGetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Query\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 839,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 804,
            "function": "insertAndSetId",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 667,
            "function": "performInsert",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 749,
            "function": "save",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/helpers.php",
            "line": 422,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.php",
            "line": 750,
            "function": "tap"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Traits/ForwardsCalls.php",
            "line": 23,
            "function": "create",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Builder",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1618,
            "function": "forwardCallTo",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.php",
            "line": 1630,
            "function": "__call",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/app/Http/Controllers/API/TransactionsController.php",
            "line": 50,
            "function": "__callStatic",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Database\\Eloquent\\Model",
            "type": "::"
        },
        {
            "function": "store",
            "class": "App\\Http\\Controllers\\API\\TransactionsController",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Controller.php",
            "line": 54,
            "function": "call_user_func_array"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/ControllerDispatcher.php",
            "line": 45,
            "function": "callAction",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Controller",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 219,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\ControllerDispatcher",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php",
            "line": 176,
            "function": "runController",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 681,
            "function": "run",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Route",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Routing\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Middleware/SubstituteBindings.php",
            "line": 41,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Middleware\\SubstituteBindings",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/Middleware/Authenticate.php",
            "line": 43,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Auth\\Middleware\\Authenticate",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 683,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 658,
            "function": "runRouteWithinStack",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 624,
            "function": "runRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Router.php",
            "line": 613,
            "function": "dispatchToRoute",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 170,
            "function": "dispatch",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Routing\\Router",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 130,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/TransformsRequest.php",
            "line": 21,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\TransformsRequest",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/ValidatePostSize.php",
            "line": 27,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\ValidatePostSize",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Middleware/CheckForMaintenanceMode.php",
            "line": 62,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Middleware\\CheckForMaintenanceMode",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/fideloper/proxy/src/TrustProxies.php",
            "line": 57,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 171,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Fideloper\\Proxy\\TrustProxies",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Pipeline/Pipeline.php",
            "line": 105,
            "function": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\{closure}",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 145,
            "function": "then",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Pipeline\\Pipeline",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Http/Kernel.php",
            "line": 110,
            "function": "sendRequestThroughRouter",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        },
        {
            "file": "/home/elihai/LaravelProjects/shekel/public/index.php",
            "line": 55,
            "function": "handle",
            "class": "Illuminate\\Foundation\\Http\\Kernel",
            "type": "->"
        }
    ]
}
```

Note: If I use `Transaction::first();`, its find the table and give me the record.

Comment: Check your `.env` file and `DB_DATABASE` parameter. It seems that you have forgot to create/set a correct DB.

Comment: can u post the whole error msg

Comment: Yes, I edited post...

Comment: @ElihaiDavidVanunu can you post your migration file for this table.?

Comment: DB name is OK. I checked in .env. And also the queries works fine. The problem is only at `save` and `create` methods. You can see the in the message the correct name of table: `transactions` but in message itself it `c`. Really wired...

Comment: @ElihaiDavidVanunu Can you post your migration ? or your table strcuture ?